# How to detect changes with Date objects in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, angular, angular2-template

Date objects that are modified using setDate method arent getting updated in template.

In template:

```
<p>{{date | date:'mediumDate'}}</p>
```

In component:

```
  nextDay(){
    this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate()+1);
  }
```

But when I call nextDay function, the template isnt updated with the new  value.

The only way I could get the change detection working was doing this:

```
  nextDay(){
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(this.date.getDate()+1);
    this.date = tomorrow;
  }
```

Are there a better way to accomplish this same task?

Comment: The `date` pipe is probably stateless, so it needs to see the `date` input property change, or the pipe won't re-execute.  As @jhadesdev mentions in his answer, since `date` is an object, and Angular only reference checks, you need to reset the reference (to a new/different object).

Comment: I gave it a shot without the pipe just now, and its the same result. If you mutate the date it won't trigger the template change, only a reference change triggers a template change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is the right way, to change the reference of the date variable. From the docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DoCheck-interface.html) we have:

> The default change detection algorithm looks for differences by comparing bound-property values by reference across change detection runs.

So if the date reference remains the same, nothing will happen. You need a new Date reference and that's why the second version of `nextDay()` works.

If you remove the formatting pipe you will see that still only the second version of `nextDay()` works.