# Updating property in class does not update the property in view

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my code in .ts Typescript file:

```
 private today: Date = new Date();
```

and this is my html

```
  <span [innerText]="today | date:dateFormat"></span>
```

This shows 22nd May perfectly

now I have a button to subtract a day from it:

```
previousDay() {
        Utils.addDays(this.today, -1);
        console.log(this.today);
    }
```

The `this.today` correctly logs 21st May in the console however my view stays at 22nd May.

Here is the plunk that I have created: https://plnkr.co/edit/6hw1JW0h5zNvF0owcU9U?p=preview

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your previousDay function as below as per plunker:

```
previousDay() {
 this.today = new Date(this.today.setDate(this.today.getDate() - 1))
 console.log(this.today); 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but that is a hack by creating new objects everytime. I want to keep the same object. If the properties are updated shouldn't the view also update by itself?

Comment: @TimLiberty, that's the correct method for two way binding in angular2 for date objects. Date objects are different from other objects.Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819057/how-to-detect-changes-with-date-objects-in-angular2

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the reference :)