# Two-way binding doesn't update property with a Date object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom two way binding (js date object) to connect smart/dumb components. I get the date object in child and emit the updated object back to parent, but it doesn't properly update the property. Is it because it's a circular reference?

I have split up the two-way binding, into a property and event binding. The event binding triggers and I run the method setting the parent property to the event from child, but it won't string interpolations in the view.

It works if I create a new Date(); andd pass the date object into, then set the property to the new date.

```
// Parent Component
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: '<child [(time)]="time"></child'
})

export class ParentComponent  {

  public time: Date = new Date();

  // I need this method to to update the time property
  public timeEvent(e: Date): void {
    this.time = new Date(e);
  }

}

// Child Component
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './.component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() private time: Date;
  @Output() private timeChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  private hour: number;
  private minute: number;

  public timeHandler(): void {
    // Handles logic and validating from input
  }

  // fires when user has selected time from picker and clicked "OK"
  public onAccept(): void {
    this.time.setHours(this.hour);
    this.time.setMinutes(this.minute);
    this.timeChange.emit(this.time);
  }
}
```

I expect time property in parent to be updated from event, emitted by child. The property seems to be updated, but view is not, until I set time to a new date object, created from date I get from child.

Comment: I don't think input or output properties should be marked private... also you dont handle the event like this `(timeChange)="timeEvent($event)"`

Comment: Try to emit a new instance of Date inside your child component, and I recommend to avoid directly modifying an @Input value.

Comment: @ric Oops, the method was just to explain what I need to do, when I break up the twoway binding. I don't actually want to use it. As Thierry says, I have emitted a new instance of the modified date object, so I can keep the two-way binding. I think it's much cleaner in the template. But why do I have to create a new instance? As far as I remember, it usually works with other objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect changes with Date objects in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819057/how-to-detect-changes-with-date-objects-in-angular2)

Comment: Date type is not an regular object, with bound properties. Angular detects changes if reference has changed (new instance) or bound properties changed (if `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`). In your case, `setHours` didn't change reference, so no detection from Angular. `new Date(time)` will create a new instance, and Angular will detect it.

Comment: @ThierryFalvo Thanks for clearing that up. I thought angular could detect change on date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change `Date` object.

```
public onAccept(): void {
  // add this line
  this.time = new Date(this.time.getTime());

  this.time.setHours(this.hour);
  this.time.setMinutes(this.minute);
  this.timeChange.emit(this.time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why I have to create a new date instance?

Comment: @cnps See my comment on your question about special Date type.